# PSexec vs Built-in Windows

Tags: powershell, wmi, psexec

So, I'm writing tools in PowerShell to execute files on remote computers. I was initially using PSexec but switched them to .net framework using win32_process. When I ran an install file on the remote machine using win32_process, it failed. And after trying gwmi win32_process on the remote machine, that failed. So accessing the wmi objects is probably the problem. Anyway! I ended up using PSexec and it succeeded, and i verified that it did. But, that got me thinking about how PSexec connects to the remote machine, and I was wondering if anyone on here knew either how I could look at PSexec source code or if someone flat out knew how it connects and executes.

I couldn't find anything on it online, just a bunch of articles about what it can do. Maybe I just suck at researching though.

Comment: There is a clone called [PAExec](https://www.poweradmin.com/paexec/) that has posted it's [source on GitHub](https://github.com/poweradminllc/PAExec)

Answer (score 1):

I have done this using the Invoke-WmiMethod cmdlet against remote machines.  You need to include any switches in your executable path but the below code sample should get you there assuming you have appropriate permissions on the local / remote hosts.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/invoke-wmimethod?view=powershell-5.1 for more details on the cmdlet.

```
#local path on the remote machine that will be run including any switches needed
$exePath = "c:\mypath\myfile.exe -s -norestart"

# Use FQDN or IP if netbios name is not reachable
$server = "myserver" 

try {
Invoke-WmiMethod -ComputerName $server -Class win32_process -Name create -ArgumentList $exePath -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null 
}
catch { 
    Write-Host "Failed to execute program on $server. Error Details: $_.Exception.Message" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

I can't speak to how PSExec works for you to compare but this method has worked for me in the past executing applications on remote hosts using only native PowerShell.

Comment: You should have `-ErrorAction Stop` on your `Invoke-WmiMethod` call not your `Out-Null` call.

Comment: Good catch.  Updated answer to reflect that.